# $\vert A \vert$ is a linear operator when $A: \mathcal{H}\to \mathcal{H}$ is linear and bounded?

Tags: hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Let $A \in \mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})$. We define $$\vert A \vert := \sqrt{A^*A}$$

Then, I've showed that $\vert A \vert$ is a self-adjoint operator, but the book I'm using also say that, for $a,b \in \mathbb{C}$ and $\psi,\phi \in \mathcal{H}$ we have

> $$\tag{1}\vert A \vert (a\psi+b\phi) = a\vert A \vert \psi + b\vert A \vert\phi$$

My question is then: How can I prove that? To me $(1)$ should **not** be linear, because of the square definition.  Can someone give me a hint?

Comment: Of course it's linear. What's the definition of that $\sqrt{A^*A}$?

Comment: What you mean by that?

Comment: Ah, I bet I see the problem. The map $A\to|A|$ is not linear on $\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})$. But that's a different question; $|A|$ is a linear map  from $\mathcal H$ to $\mathcal H$.

Comment: We say that $A^*A$ is positive, then exists some $C$ selfadjoint such that $C^2 = A^*A$, so we say $C = \vert A \vert$

Comment: What do you mean, what do I mean? You said $|A|=\sqrt{A^*A}$, and I asked for the definition of $\sqrt{A^*A}$.

Comment: I think that the squart function comes from the continuous functional calculus

Comment: "There exists some $C$ selfadjoint" _what_? There exists a selfadjoint linear operator $C$ such that... is the actual definition. $C$ is linear, by the defintion.

Comment: Continuous functional calculus, great. That defines, under some circumstances, a _linear operator_ $f(T)$...

Comment: Oh!! This comes from the Continuous Functional Calculus then, because the Gelfand Homomorphism is a algebra isomorphism then it **must** be frue that the squared function is a linear operator where the $f = \sqrt{\cdot}$ is identified with the Gelfand Homomorphism $\phi(f)$. Is this what you mean?

Comment: And the Gelfand Homomorphism satisfy that $\phi(af+bg)  = a\phi(f)+b\phi(g)$ by its nature definition?

Comment: I'm not sure whether that's what I mean, not being sure what you mean. Consider an example. Say $A$ is a multiplication operator on $L^2$, so $Af=mf$ for some $m\in L^\infty$. Then $|A|$ is also a multiplication operator, given by $|A|f=|m|f$. That's linear - the non-linearity of the map $z\mapsto|z|$ is irrelevant.

Comment: So then I really think that I'm not able to set my question better. It really seams to me that, because I do not understand what you say using the definition answer (without my reasoning)

Comment: Sorry, but it seems to me there's no point to trying to set your question better: Whatever your reason for thinking $|A|$ should not be linear is, it's _wrong_. It really is clear from the definition that $|A|$ is linear. Hmm. If $T$ is linear you believe that $T^2$ is linear, in spite of that square, right?

Comment: You say "I've showed that $|A|$ is a self-adjoint operator". In this context "operator" _means_ "linear operator".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*By definition*, $|A|$ is the *linear* positive semidefinite operator with $|A||A|=A^*A$.

Regarding "should not be linear, because of the square definition": If we define $Abs:\mathcal B(\mathcal H)\to\mathcal B(\mathcal H)$ by $Abs(A)=|A|$ then $Abs$ is not linear, perhaps "because of the square definition". That has nothing to do with the fact that $Abs(A)$ is linear.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's beneficial to consider a finite dimensional case for clarification.

Consider the matrix
\begin{align}
A = 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0  & \sqrt{-1}\\
0 & -1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & -1
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
then we have
\begin{align}
A^\ast A = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0  & \sqrt{-1}\\
0 & 1 & 0\\
-\sqrt{-1} & 0 & 2
\end{pmatrix} 
\end{align}
which is Hermitian and diagonalizable. In particular, we see that
\begin{align}
A^\ast A = 
U
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & \frac{3-\sqrt{5}}{2} & 0\\
0 & 0 & \frac{3+\sqrt{5}}{2}
\end{pmatrix}
U^{\ast}
\end{align}
where $U$ is some unitary matrix.

By definition (or functional calculus), we have that
\begin{align}
|A|=\sqrt{A^\ast A} := U
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & \sqrt{\frac{3-\sqrt{5}}{2}} & 0\\
0 & 0 & \sqrt{\frac{3+\sqrt{5}}{2}}
\end{pmatrix}
U^{\ast}
\end{align}
which by definition is linear.

**Remark:** One should note that $A^\ast A$ has only nonnegative eigenvalues which makes defining the square root matrix possible.

Comment: Great answer! This were very pedagogic. Thanks!